# How to set dynamic uitablviewcell height according to a custom xib height with uistackview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, stack, uistackview

I cannot set UITableViewcell to have dynamic height.

I have a custom xib and the structure as below,
and already add leading, trailing and top constraint to stack view to its superview

[image]
[image]

```
class fieldView: UIView {
let kCONTENT_XIB_NAME = "form_field_view"

@IBOutlet weak var contectView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var fieldDesc: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var fieldInput: customTextField!

var required: Bool?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(kCONTENT_XIB_NAME, owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contectView)
    contectView.frame = self.bounds
    contectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    fieldInput.isScrollEnabled = false
}
```

}

In tableView cellForRowAt, I create the custom view and add it to each UITableViewCell

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(fieldView)
NSLayoutConstraint(item: fieldView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: fieldView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100.0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: fieldView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: fieldView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottomMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
return cell
```

for tableView

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fieldTable.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    fieldTable.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (expanded) {
        return (UITableView.automaticDimension)
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}
```

However the actual result like this

[image]

I think the UIStackView was change its height, but its superview not changed, that make tableviewcell no changes too

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the use of "cell.contentView.addSubview(fieldView)" ?

Comment: add the custom xib view to tableViewCell

Comment: You need to show ***how*** you *"create the custom view and add it to each `UITableViewCell`"* -- most likely, you are not setting constraints properly at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lastly I figure it out this question

by just add these two line

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

called when textfield content changed

Answer (score -1):

First you have to count the number of lines of UILabel

```
 NSInteger lineCount = 0;
 CGSize textSize = CGSizeMake(yourLabel.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);
 int rHeight = lroundf([yourLabel sizeThatFits:textSize].height);
 int charSize = lroundf(yourLabel.font.lineHeight);
 lineCount = rHeight/charSize;
 NSLog(@"No of lines: %i",lineCount);
```

else you can take extension to count max line of label

```
extension UILabel {
    func calculateMaxLines() -> Int {
        let maxSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(Float.infinity))
        let charSize = font.lineHeight
        let text = (self.text ?? "") as NSString
        let textSize = text.boundingRect(with: maxSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
        let linesRoundedUp = Int(ceil(textSize.height/charSize)) 
        return linesRoundedUp
    }    
}
```

Use that:

```
let lineCount = YourLabel. calculateMaxLines
```

Now Set the height for each line of label

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return lineCount * 18 //If total 3 line so 3*18 = 54 is height else you can take any number instead of 18 according to font size height
}
```